# Approval process is not installed in package

Tags: apex, managed-package

My requirement is Approval process is not installed in package, is there any other way to do this approval process install for package?

Comment: Have you included approval process in your package ?

Comment: yes, but while included in package it doesn't take.  for that any other way?

Comment: do you see any error / alert message?

Comment: as per http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_packageable_components.htm you should be able to include workflow to your package

Answer (score 1):

You can't package an Approval Process. You can, however, package all of its components. We have a package where the config screen uses Andy Fawcett's excellent [Apex Wrapper for the MetaData API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to post a zip of the Approval Process definition metadata back into the org.

I created a zip of a package that just contains the approval process definition xmls and a package.xml, and stored it as a Document in the package. Then the config screen controller asks the user to create a Remote Site of the Org's own URL (so the metadata API can talk back into the org) and confirm that it's done.

After that, the config screen controller can read the zip file back out of Documents and post it into the Org.

Of course this means that the Approval Process itself (if not the components it is made from) is locally defined and can be altered within the local org. That's not a problem for my situation.